# What is $\mathbb Q^{\mathrm{hypoab}}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}\newcommand{\ab}{\mathrm{ab}}$Let $G(\mathbb Q) = \Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q} / \mathbb Q)$ be the absolute Galois group. It's well-known that the abelianization $G(\mathbb Q)^{\ab}$ of $G(\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to $\Aut(\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z) = \widehat {\mathbb Z}^\times$, and that the fixed field $\mathbb Q^{\ab}$ of the commutator subgroup of $G(\mathbb Q)$ may be constructed by adjoining all roots of unity to $\mathbb Q$.

Abelian Galois groups are generalized by solvable Galois groups, or more generally hypoabelian Galois groups (recall that a group is hypoabelian if its derived series stabilizes at the trivial group, possibly after transfinitely many steps).

**Question 1:** What is the hypoabelianization of $G(\mathbb Q)$?

**Question 2:** What is the fixed field of the maximal perfect normal subgroup of $G(\mathbb Q)$?

(Recall that in general, the maximal perfect normal subgroup is the subgroup at which the derived series stabilizes, possibly after transfinitely many steps; the hypoabelianization of a group is its quotient by its maximal perfect normal subgroup.)

Comment: Your definition of hypoabelian group is absurd: a group has its upper central series stabilizing at the trivial group iff it has a trivial center. Also, on the web, hypoabelian seems to mean that the transfinite derived series stabilizes at the trivial group. So probably "upper central series" should be "transfinite derived series" (twice).

Comment: Not your question, but note that the maximal *soluble* extension is given by repeatedly adjoining all radicals, i.e. the colimit of $K_{i+1} = K_i\big(\sqrt[\mathbf N]{K_i^\times}\big)$ (maybe start with $K_0 = \mathbf Q^{\operatorname{ab}}$ instead of $K_0 = \mathbf Q$). It's already not so obvious to me what the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K_\infty/\mathbf Q)$ is, but presumably people have thought about this.

Comment: @YCor -- Thanks -- I meant "derived series". Here I was thinking that there were only two "series" to worry about -- upper and lower -- and that one corresponded to nilpotence while the other corresponded to solvability.  But apparently there are actually at least three "series" of this type, and the analogy in my head between nilpotence and solvability is not reflected in an analogy between the names of the associated series...

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn If we start with the maximal abelian extension $k$, then the Kummer theory seems to tell us that the absolute Galois group of $k$ is the cofiltered limit of $\mu_n(k)\otimes(k^\times/k^{\times n})^\vee$? I do not know whether this is computable.

Comment: @Z.M some version thereof will be the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/\mathbf Q^{\operatorname{ab}})$, yeah. But when you iterate this procedure, e.g. to solve cubics using Cardano's (or really Del Ferro's) formula, you get extensions of such things. Even if you could compute $K_0^\times/(K_0^\times)^n$, doing the same for higher $K_i$'s seems intractable.

Comment: If it's possible to describe even the maximal quotient of $G(\mathbb Q)$ of derived length 2 (i.e. the maximal quotient of $G(\mathbb Q)$ which is an extension of an abelian group by another abelian group), that would be an interesting start I think.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421107/what-is-mathbb-q-mathrmhypoab?noredirect=1#comment1081832_421107) I'm not sure I understand -- usually a "solvable" group (which I think is the same as "soluble"?) is required to have a derived series of _finite_ length, but this closure under radicals surely will result in length $\omega$ at least, right? Anyway I'd be curious to understand what things look like even after going a step or two along this tower of extensions.

Comment: @TimCampion you're absolutely right; I naively took the colimit of soluble extensions and claimed it is soluble. It's only pro-soluble, which happens to be the same thing as (topologically) hypoabelian; see my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421232/82179) below (this was already present in YCor's comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421107/what-is-mathbb-q-mathrmhypoab?noredirect=1#comment1081832_421107), Wojowu's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421125/82179), YCor's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421107/what-is-mathbb-q-mathrmhypoab?noredirect=1#comment1081902_421125), and Z. M's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421107/what-is-mathbb-q-mathrmhypoab?noredirect=1#comment1081944_421107) already contain everything we need. Let me provide a little more detail here. I will shift the indices by $1$ for reasons that will become apparent:

**Definition.** Set $K_0 = \mathbf Q$ and let $K_1 = \mathbf Q(\boldsymbol \mu)$ be the field obtained by adjoining the roots of unity $\boldsymbol \mu \subseteq \bar{\mathbf Q}$. Inductively define $K_{i+1}=K_i\big(\sqrt[\infty\ \ ]{K_i^\times}\big)$, and set $K_\infty = \underset{\substack{\longrightarrow \\ i}}{\operatorname{colim}} K_i$.

We claim that this is the extension we're after. We first introduce some notation:

**Definition.** Given a profinite group $G$, its (*profinte*) *derived series* is the transfinite chain of *closed* subgroups
$$G = G^{(0)} \trianglerighteq G^{(1)} \trianglerighteq \cdots \trianglerighteq G^{(\alpha)} \trianglerighteq \cdots$$
defined by $G^{(\alpha+1)} = \overline{[G^{(\alpha)},G^{(\alpha)}]}$ and $G^{(\beta)} = \bigcap_{\alpha < \beta} G^{(\alpha)}$ for any limit ordinal $\beta$ (which is already closed as each $G^{(\alpha)}$ is closed). One could alter the notation to distinguish it from the abstract derived series, but I will never use the latter (the same goes for the Kronecker–Weber theorem: it computes the *topological* abelianisation, not the abstract one!). Note that for any continuous surjective homomorphism $G \to H$ of profinite groups, the image of $G^{(\alpha)}$ is $H^{(\alpha)}$.

**Lemma.** *Let $G$ be a profinite group. Then $G^{(\omega + 1)} = G^{(\omega)}$, and this group is trivial if and only if $G$ is pro-soluble¹.*

*Proof.* For any finite group $G$, the descending chain $G^{(i)}$ stabilises after finitely many steps, so $G^{(\omega + 1)} = G^{(\omega)}$. The same statement for profinite groups follows since any closed normal subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$ is the intersection of the open normal subgroups $U \trianglelefteq G$ containing it. Similarly, $G^{(\omega)} = 1$ if and only if the same holds in every finite quotient $G/U$, i.e. if and only if all $G/U$ are soluble. $\square$

Let's denote $G^{(\omega)}$ by $G^{(\infty)}$. For $n \in \mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}$, we will say that $G$ is *$n$-soluble* if $G^{(n)} = 1$, and we write $G^{n\text{-}\!\operatorname{sol}} = G/G^{(n)}$ for its maximal $n$-soluble quotient (in which we omit $n$ if $n = \infty$). For instance, $G$ is $1$-soluble if and only if it is abelian, and $\infty$-soluble if and only if it is pro-soluble (equivalently, hypoabelian as profinite group).

**Theorem.** *Let $\Gamma = \Gamma_{\mathbf Q}$ be the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf Q$.*

1. *For $n \in \mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}$, the fixed field of $\Gamma^{(n)}$ is $K_n$ (i.e. $K_n$ is the maximal pro-soluble extension of derived length $\leq n$);*
2. *For $n \in \mathbf N \setminus \{0\}$, the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K_{n+1}/K_n) = \Gamma^{(n)}/\Gamma^{(n+1)}$ is isomorphic to*
   $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{cont}}\!\big(K_n^\times,\hat{\mathbf Z}(1)\big),$$
   *where $K^\times$ has the discrete topology and $\hat{\mathbf Z}(1) = \lim_m \boldsymbol \mu_m$ is the Tate module of $\bar{\mathbf Q}^\times$.*

*Proof.* Statement (1) is trivial for $n=0$, and is the Kronecker–Weber theorem for $n=1$. Statements (1) and (2) for finite $n \geq 2$ follow inductively by Kummer theory (see the corollary below). Finally, statement (1) for $n = \infty$ follows from the statement at finite levels, since $K_\infty = \bigcup_n K_n$ and $G^{(\infty)} = \bigcap_n G^{(n)}$. $\square$

Note also that the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/K_0)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}(\boldsymbol \mu) = \hat{\mathbf Z}^\times$. However, explicitly computing $\operatorname{Gal}(K_{n+1}/K_n)$ in a meaninful way is pretty hard, let alone saying anything about how the various pieces fit together.

---

**Edit:** After writing this answer, I became aware of the following two striking results:

**Theorem** (Iwasawa). *The Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K_\infty/K_1) = \Gamma^{(1)}/\Gamma^{(\infty)}$ is a* free *pro-soluble group $\widehat{F_\omega}^{\operatorname{sol}}$ on countably infinitely many generators.*

So we know that $\Gamma^{\operatorname{sol}}$ sits in a short exact sequence
$$1 \to \widehat{F_\omega}^{\operatorname{sol}} \to \Gamma^{\operatorname{sol}} \to \hat{\mathbf Z}^\times \to 1.$$
I find it hard to imagine that this sequence splits as a semi-direct product (but I am more optimistic about the derived length $\leq 2$ situation).

**Theorem** (Shafarevich). *Any finite soluble group $G$ occurs as a quotient of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_\infty/\mathbf Q) = \Gamma^{\operatorname{sol}}$.*

A modern reference is Neukirch–Schmidt–Wingberg's *Cohomology of number fields*, Corollary 9.5.4 (Iwasawa) and Theorem 9.6.1 (Shafarevich). (This is a truly great book, but even at $>800$ pages it can be a bit terse at times.)

---

We used the following general result:

**Lemma** (Kummer theory). *Let $m \in \mathbf Z_{>0}$, and $K$ be a field of characteristic not dividing $m$ that contains $\boldsymbol \mu_m$.*

1. *The maximal abelian extension of exponent $m$ of $K$ is $L=K\big(\sqrt[m\ \ ]{K^\times}\big)$;*
2. *The map*
   \begin{align*}
    \operatorname{Gal}(L/K) = \Gamma_K^{\operatorname{ab}}/m &\to \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{cont}}\!\big(K^\times,\boldsymbol \mu_m\big) = \left(K^\times/(K^\times)^m\right)^\vee \\
    \sigma &\mapsto \left(a \mapsto \frac{\sigma(\sqrt[m\ \ ]{a})}{\sqrt[m\ \ ]{a}}\right)
    \end{align*}
   *is an isomorphism of profinite groups, where $K^\times/(K^\times)^m$ has the discrete topology and $A^\vee$ denotes the Pontryagin dual of a locally compact abelian group $A$.*

We avoid the notation $\widehat A$ for Pontryagin duals, since it clashes with the notation for profinite completions. (Note that Z. M's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421107/what-is-mathbb-q-mathrmhypoab?noredirect=1#comment1081944_421107) uses $(-)^\vee$ for a linear dual, which differs from my notation by a Tate twist.)

Because it's not very hard, let's include a proof.

*Proof.* For (2), by Pontryagin duality it suffices to show that the dual map
\begin{align*}
K^\times/(K^\times)^m &\to \operatorname{Hom}\!\big(\Gamma_K,\boldsymbol \mu_m\big) = \left(\Gamma_K^{\operatorname{ab}}/m\right)^\vee \\
a &\mapsto \left(\sigma \mapsto \frac{\sigma(\sqrt[m\ \ ]{a})}{\sqrt[m\ \ ]{a}}\right)
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism. Note that it is well-defined since any two $m$-th roots of $a$ differ (multiplicatively) by an element of $\boldsymbol \mu_m \subseteq K$, on which $\sigma$ acts as the identity. Since $\boldsymbol \mu_m \subseteq K$, the $\Gamma_K$-module $\boldsymbol \mu_m$ has trivial action, so $\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{cont}}(\Gamma_K,\boldsymbol \mu_m) = H^1(K,\boldsymbol \mu_m)$. The Kummer sequence
$$1 \to \boldsymbol \mu_m \to \mathbf G_m \stackrel{(-)^m}\to \mathbf G_m \to 1$$
and Hilbert's theorem 90 compute $K^\times/(K^\times)^m \stackrel\sim\to H^1(K,\boldsymbol \mu_m)$ via the map above. Now (1) follows since $\sigma \in \Gamma_K$ is in the kernel of $\Gamma_K \to \big(K^\times/(K^\times)^m\big)^\vee$ if and only if $\sigma$ fixes all $m$-th roots of elements in $K$. $\square$

**Corollay.** *Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$ containing $\boldsymbol \mu$.*

1. *The maximal abelian extension of $K$ is $L=K\big(\sqrt[\infty\ \ ]{K^\times}\big)$.*
2. *The map*
   \begin{align*}
    \operatorname{Gal}(L/K) &\to \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{cont}}\!\big(K^\times,\hat{\mathbf Z}(1)\big) \\
    \sigma &\to \left(a \mapsto \left(\frac{\sigma(\sqrt[m\ \ ]{a})}{\sqrt[m\ \ ]{a}}\right)_{m \in \mathbf Z_{>0}}\right)
    \end{align*}
   *is an isomorphism of profinite groups.*

*Proof.* Take inverse limits over all $m \in \mathbf Z_{>0}$ in the lemma above, noting that the inverse limit pulls out of $\operatorname{Hom}(K^\times,-)$. $\square$

---

¹Linguistic footnote: *soluble* and *solvable* mean the same thing. I used to think that this is one of those BrE vs AmE things (for instance, my Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary does not contain the word *solvable* at all). But I think some folks in the UK also use *solvable*, so it's not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Solvable and soluble is definitely an issue of AmE vs. BrE in terms of origins.  If solvable has gained traction in the UK, maybe that's a long-term effect of seeing it in books and papers written in AmE.  I think the use of "maths" would be much more difficult to change.

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic! I think I will return to this answer more than once in my life to refresh my image of the big picture, to eventually learn how Kummer theory works (your proof of this lemma makes it sound comprehensible!), and to follow up on those  references to the results of Iwasawa and so forth.

Comment: I'm just realising I might have been a little careless with pulling out the limit in the final corollary. On a set-theoretic level this seems ok, but these Hom sets naturally carry topologies as well. I think that the limit topology that we want is not actually the compact open topology (although I suppose I never claimed it was...).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This answer is incorrect, see comments. I've assumed hypoabelianness is preserved under quotients, which is not the case.

An algebraic extension $L/K$ is hypoabelian iff it is prosolvable, i.e. $L$ is a union of finite solvable extensions of $K$. Indeed, since Galois groups are residually finite, it is easy to see $Gal(L/K)$ is hypoabelian iff all its finite quotients are (this is easy to see using the perfect core characterization), and a finite group is hypoabelian group iff it is solvable.

Therefore, the maximal hypoabelian extension of $\mathbb Q$ (or any field) is the maximal (pro)solvable extension, which as R. van Dobben de Bruyn mentions in the comments, is the maximal radical extension, i.e. it is formed by repeatedly adjoining all roots of all elements of the field.

Comment: Great, thanks -- that's a very concrete description of the field! As maybe obvious from the question, I don't really know very much number theory -- is the description of the corresponding Galois group more complicated?

Comment: A free group on $\ge 2$ generators is residually finite hypoabelian (and even residually-(finite nilpotent)) but its finite quotients are not all hypoabelian (i.e., are not all solvable). If such an assertion is used, it should make use of being profinite.

Comment: @YCor Ah, I'm afraid you are right. I've implicitly assumed that hypoabelianness is preserved under quotients, just like regular solvability, but we get problems at limit stages of the derived series (intersections don't commute with projections). I think profiniteness doesn't help - you can similarly produce examples using free profinite groups, but I didn't check they are hypoabelian.

Comment: @Wojowu If you define hypoabelian in the topological category (i.e., using the transfinite closed derived series: $G_{n+1}=\overline{[G_n,G_n]}$), compactness definitely helps: if $G$ is a compact, topologically hypoabelian group, then every finite Hausdorff quotient of $G$ is solvable. In particular, free profinite groups on $\ge 2$ generators are not topologically hypoabelian. However I'm not sure about the derived series.

Comment: I would be happy to take "hypoabelian" in the topological sense if that simplifies things.

Comment: @TimCampion of course hypoabelian in the topological sense is the *only sensible* thing to do. The Kronecker–Weber theorem also says nothing about the abstract abelianisation. I wrote an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421232/82179) collecting all of the ideas here (with details).